Type-safe routes with [locale] pathname segment
What's the best approach to typing app routes for an i18n app? Previously I just read the request headers (cookies and accept-language) to get the locale, and the experiemental typedRoutes feature worked perfectly. I was recently convinced to move the locale into the pathname. I can still write paths without including the locale segment. The middleware then redirects to the correct path by doing the same lookup as before. However it would save a round-trip and a little compute to just include the current locale in the path to begin with. I'm using i18next if that matters.
// src/i18n/settings.ts

import { InitOptions } from "i18next";
import type { Route } from "next";

import * as config from "@/services/config-service/service-public.mjs";

export const SUPPORTED_LOCALES = ["en-US"] as const;

export const FALLBACK_LOCALE = SUPPORTED_LOCALES[0];

export type SupportedLocale = (typeof SUPPORTED_LOCALES)[number];

export const cookieName = config.i18nName;

export const getOptions = () =>
    ({
        debug: config.debugI18n,
        fallbackLng: FALLBACK_LOCALE,
        supportedLngs: SUPPORTED_LOCALES
    }) satisfies InitOptions as InitOptions;

export const i18nPathname = <
    Locale extends SupportedLocale,
    LogicalPathname = string extends Route<`/${Locale}${infer Pathname}`>
        ? Pathname
        : never
>(
    locale: SupportedLocale,
    logicalPathname: LogicalPathname
) => (logicalPathname === "/" ? `/${locale}` : `/${locale}${logicalPathname}`);

// some random page or action

redirect(i18nPathname(locale, "/profile/welcome"));
redirect(`/${locale}/profile/welcome`);

I don't get any type errors with this, but the return type for i18nPathname() is just string. I also don't get any help from autocomplete. I can't see any difference between my function and just using interpolation directly.

Is there a way to get pathname typing correct (autocomplete, typo checks)?
Is there another approach that would get me closer to my goal?

I've see the path generation in TanStack Router. I'd love to be able to use that with Next!

Edit:
Here's my app folder structure. There shouldn't be anything surprising in there.
t --only-dirs src/app
src/app/
├── [locale]/
│  ├── _actions/
│  ├── about/
│  ├── design-system/
│  │  ├── cards/
│  │  ├── elevation/
│  │  ├── input/
│  │  ├── interactive/
│  │  ├── palette/
│  │  ├── table/
│  │  └── typography/
│  ├── profile/
│  │  ├── verification/
│  │  │  └── _actions/
│  │  ├── verification-prompt/
│  │  │  └── _actions/
│  │  └── welcome/
│  ├── profiles/
│  │  └── new/
│  │     └── _actions/
│  └── sessions/
│     ├── assistance/
│     │  └── password/
│     │     ├── _actions/
│     │     ├── new/
│     │     │  └── _actions/
│     │     └── prompt/
│     └── new/
│        └── _actions/
└── api/
   └── cron/
      ├── password-resets/
      └── sessions/

Edit 2:
Here's how Route is defined by Next:
export type Route<T extends string = string> =
  __next_route_internal_types__.RouteImpl<T>

In the same file (.next/types/link.d.ts), here's an excerpt of __next_route_internal_types__. Obviously StaticRoutes and DynamicRoutes will differ from app to app.
type SafeSlug<S extends string> = S extends `${string}/${string}`
  ? never
  : S extends `${string}${SearchOrHash}`
  ? never
  : S extends ''
  ? never
  : S

// ...

type StaticRoutes = 
  | `/api/cron/password-resets`
  | `/api/cron/sessions`
type DynamicRoutes<T extends string = string> = 
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/about`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/profile/verification`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/profile/verification-prompt`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions/assistance`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions/assistance/password/new`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/profile`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/profile/welcome`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions/assistance/password`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions/new`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions/assistance/password/prompt`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/sessions`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/profiles/new`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/input`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/palette`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/table`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/cards`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/interactive`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/typography`
  | `/${SafeSlug<T>}/design-system/elevation`

type RouteImpl<T> = 
  | StaticRoutes
  | SearchOrHash
  | WithProtocol
  | `${StaticRoutes}${SearchOrHash}`
  | (T extends `${DynamicRoutes<infer _>}${Suffix}` ? T : never)

I do plan to incorporate more dynamic path params besides [locale]. I just haven't built them yet.

I haven't done this before so bear with me. You could use a top level dynamic route for locale. Then make a custom hook that uses useRouter to get the locale value and return the t function. Or have the layout file in the dyanmic locale route change the language.

For redirection, I'd have the layout file in the locale segment check if the route value is a valid locale, if yes, don't redirect, if not then redirect to a certain locale. Otherwise change locale through interaction (i.e. language picker), which will redirect to the relevant locale route and the layout file will handle the rest based on the logic in my previous comment.

Getting the locale isn't an issue. My issue is typing the function so the path autocompletes.

Quick clarification, your locale route is a dynamic route right?

@Brother58697 yes. I only have one locale at the moment, but I'd like to see more contributed.

But ultimately, regardless of the number of locales, it's still one route/folder right? The layout just reads the value of the route and updates the language right?

Yes one [locale] route at the root of the routing tree.

There's no autocomplete because the routes are in the form of /[locale]/rest/of/route and not /en-US/rest/of/route, so the parameter types aren't being inferred correctly.
Instead we just need to use a type that infer the path past /[locale] and use that type for our path parameter.
type Route = "api/" | "/[locale]/" | "/[locale]/profile/welcome" | "/[locale]/profile/settings" | "/[locale]/users/posts"

// Use distributive conditional to ignore routes that don't start with /[locale] like /api
type RoutePastLocale = Route extends infer J ? J extends `/[locale]${infer I}` ? I : never : never;

export const SUPPORTED_LOCALES = ["en-US"] as const;

type Locale = typeof SUPPORTED_LOCALES[number]

function i18nPathname(locale: Locale, path: RoutePastLocale) {
  return `${locale}${path}`;
}

const home = i18nPathname('en-US', '/'); // Correct autocomplete on path

Playground

Where does Route get defined? I'd assume Next generates it somewhere. Can I import it?

When you import the Route type in your snippet using the typedRoutes setting, what does the type look like? I actually haven't used that setting before and just assumed it creates a union of strings.

I updated the question to include the dynamically generated types the Next provides.

That's a rough one brother. Without direct access to DynamicRoutes, I can't move forward. At best, you can use Route for validation though, that's what it's meant to be used for I think.

No worries! I found a discussion on GitHub where someone was asking for more-or-less the same thing, but general. I left a comment that would enable exactly what I want, but for now I guess it's just not possible.

Just took a look at it. If that goes through, it'll be pretty helpful and basically solve your case in the most elegant way too.
